# What's the RewriteRule to redirect all pages in a folder to a single URL (the Homepage)?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

Hi I want to 301 redirect all urls, including the folder name, within the portfolio folder to the homepage.

There are plenty of similar questions/answers, but the ones I could find focused on simply removing the folder from the URL. I don't want that. I need to redirect to a single URL. i.e. remove everything from the source URL and redirect to the homepage.

example of urls I want to redirect

```
https://example.com/portfolio/
https://example.com/portfolio
https://example.com/portfolio/this-is-a-page
https://example.com/portfolio/this-is-a-another-page
```

I've used this regex below, but it doesn't work because instead of redirecting to the homepage, it redirects from:
https://example.com/portfolio/this-is-a-page
to
https://example.com/this-is-a-page

I need it to redirect to just https://example.com/ whatever the /portfolio/ child url. What am I doing wrong?

```
^/?portfolio/(.*)$
https://example.com/$1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
^/?portfolio(/|$)
https://example.com/
```

Without `$1` ,  because this `$1`  is just there to copy the end of the URL

Rewrite with:

```
RewriteRule ^/?portfolio(/|$) / [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: It comes up with some pattern errors when I test it on https://regex101.com/ and I also can't get it to work. It redirects to the homepage but keeps the child part of the URL and so goes to a 404.

Comment: This seems to work for the children, but doesn't work for the folder: RewriteRule  ^portfolio/. / [R=301,L]

Comment: Thank you @Croises - it now works! I appreciate your help a lot. I didn't realise I needed help with the rewriterule as well, but obviously I did. I updated the question to help future searchers.